# Then either or then too?

Tags: conjunctions, run-on-sentences

> I made a choice the last time I was here and I didn't see any, then either and I failed

Is this statement grammatically correct? I have some doubts around the "then either" part.

The meaning I want it to convey is that I made a choice the last time I was here (as in the situation I am in), and I was not able to see any choices. I am not seeing any choices now too. And I failed the last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for negative statements (usually involving the word '**not**'), you should use '**either**'.

Example:

> I don't see any choices now. I didn't then, either.

You should use **too** when you are making a positive or neutral statement.

Example:

> I went to the store yesterday. I went today, too.

---

It's also worth noting that the structure of your sentence is a little awkward. I'm also confused by

> I made a choice

and

> I didn't see any choices

It seems like these are contradictory. Perhaps an alternative sentence could read like this:

> I tried to make a choice the last time I was here and couldn't see any, and I don't see any this time, either.

Answer (score 3):

The punctuation is wrong and this makes it confusing.

What I *think* you mean is

> I made a choice the last time I was here, and I didn't see any then either, and I failed.

There are 3 clauses here

1. I made a choice last time I was here.
2. I didn't see any (last time I was here)  (either this time or last time)
3. I failed.

In speech, it might be clear what you are talking about from context or from intonation.  In writing, you should rephrase, and perhaps link the clauses together more meaningfully, or split into separate sentences.